# How to add ALT or Title attribute in WordPress for mobile menu icon

Tags: wordpress, tags, accessibility, anchor, alt

I am using a WordPress theme that I am trying to make 100% accessible. I cant get any help from the developer and I am not very good at the back end of WordPress. I need help with this:

[ 2.4 Navigable: Provide ways to help users navigate, find content, and determine where they are. ] 
a (anchor) element must contain text. The text may occur in the anchor text or in the title attribute of the anchor or in the Alt text of an image used within the anchor.

This is the code in the theme:

```
<div class="qodef-mobile-menu-opener">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                <span class="qodef-mobile-opener-icon-holder">
                    <i class="qodef-icon-font-awesome fa fa-bars " ></i>                    </span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

Where in WordPress is this code located so I can insert a title attribute or Alt text.

Thank You!

Comment: depends entirely on the theme and whether this is in the header, footer, a widget within the WordPress backend you can edit directly etc. You can get to all the theme files in the folder "wp-content/themes/your-theme-name" if you have the files or FTP access to the server. You can also use the built in editor located in the WordPress admin area 'Appearance->Editor' but make sure you know what you are doing before using this.